# Wildcards in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, coldfusion

we have hundreds of coldfusion files that need 301 redirecting.

they follow this format: /info2.cfm?info_id=[id]

e.g:

`www.example.com/info2.cfm?info_id=102555
www.example.com/info2.cfm?info_id=109180
www.example.com/info2.cfm?info_id=106167`

How would we go about redirecting all URLs that contain any of the above to the root domain? So basically 301 redirecting all URLs than contain

`info2.cfm?info_id=`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)info_id=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^info2\.cfm$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `Redirect` via your httpd.conf (or other .conf file) in Apache (assuming you're using Apache). Within that, there will be an option to add your redirects. You can either include

```
Redirect info2.cfm where_you_want_it_to_redirect
<Directory where_you_want_it_to_redirect>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

or...

```
RedirectMatch info2.cfm(.*) where_you_want_it_to_redirect$1
<Directory where_you_want_it_to_redirect>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

...if you'd also like to regex functionality.

Each time you do it too, you'll need to restart Apache.

Comment: I believe httpd.conf edits are not necessary for 301 redirects. EDIT after your edit, man you overdid that.